# How to use regex in recursrion

Tags: python

`input = '''name Jhon age 30
name John bp 130 90
name Rick age 80
name Rick bp 110 70'''`

I have a string like the above one.

I need to make it as list of dicts

```
[ 
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age" : 30,
        "bp_sys" : 130,
       "bp_dia" : 90
   },
   {
       "name": "Rick",
       "age" : 80,
       "bp_sys" : 110,
       "bp_dia" : 70
   }
]
```

I have tried in the below - which splits the input by line and applying regex on each line

```
for line in input.split("\n"):
    print re.findall(r'name (.*?) age (.*?)', line)
```

It prints something like `[('John', '')]` for the first line

Any other easy way?

Comment: is the input always in the same format?

Comment: Yes. It will b in the same format

Comment: It prints `['Jhon']` for the first line, as you can see [here](https://ideone.com/DOrA0B). You must be using either some other inputs or some other code.

Comment: Yes It prints for me too. I need age also in the same line like `[('John') , '30')]`

Comment: Then you need to match the age in your regex.

Comment: I have tried this too to get the age `re.findall(r'name (.*?) age (.*?)', line)`

Comment: What recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` from itertools and regex.

**Demo:**

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

inputVal = '''name John age 30
name John bp 130 90
name Rick age 80
name Rick bp 110 70'''

inputVal = inputVal.splitlines()
res = []
for key, group in groupby(inputVal, lambda x: re.findall(r'(?<=name\s).*?(?=\s)', x)[0]):
    d = {"name": key}
    for i in group:
        if "age" in i:
            val = i.split()
            d["age"] = int(val[-1])
        if "bp" in i:
            val = i.split()
            d["bp_sys"] = int(val[-2])
            d["bp_dia"] = int(val[-1])
    res.append(d)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'age': 30, 'bp_sys': 130, 'name': 'John', 'bp_dia': 90}, {'age': 80, 'bp_sys': 110, 'name': 'Rick', 'bp_dia': 70}]
```

- I am using name as key. Ex: `'John'`, `'Rick'`

Answer (score 1):

Here another try with regex :

```
import re

input1 = '''name John age 30
name John bp 130 90
name Rick age 80
name Rick bp 110 70'''

l1 = re.findall(r'name (.*?) age (.\d)', input1)
l2 = [re.findall(r'name {name} bp (.\d*) (.\d*)'.format(name=i[0]), input1) for i in l1]
sub_list = [list(i) + list(sum(j, ())) for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
main_list = []
for i in sub_list:
    dct = {"name": i[0], 'age': i[1], "bp_sys": i[2], "bp_dia": i[3]}
    main_list.append(dct)
print(main_list)
```

Comment: Can I get any solution using recursion